# Excel 2016 breaks previously working VBA macro

Tags: macos, excel, excel-2016, vba

I have developed a small VBA macro in Excel that's supposed to add the values of cells in row 15 to the values of cells in row 6 during workbook change (in my case entering a number in row 15 and pressing tab).

Initially, I developed and used it in Excel 2013, then I have switched to Mac and have since used it in Excel for Mac 2011. Now, I have installed Excel for Mac 2016 and all of a sudden, the macro doesn't work anymore.

This is the script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C15:H15")) > 0 Then
            Call copySub
    End If
End Sub

Sub copySub()
    Sheets("sheet1").Protect , UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    For i = 3 To 8
        Cells(6, i).Value = Cells(6, i).Value + Cells(15, i).Value
        Cells(15, i).Value = 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

When I enter a value and press tab in Excel 2016, I get the runtime error 91 "Object variable or With block variable not set". The error seems to occur in the line:

```
Cells(6, i).Value = Cells(6, i).Value + Cells(15, i).Value
```

I have also tried to store the sum in a variable before assigning it to `Cells(6, i).Value`, but that didn't help either.

Did Microsoft change the logic of the sheet protection, especially with the parameter `UserInterFaceOnly` set to `true`? Or what's going on here?

I hope you can help me.

Thanks,
chuky

Comment: add a reference to the sheet e.g. `Sheets("Sheet1").cells(6,i).value = ...`

Comment: Thanks for the idea SeanC but it's still not working...

Comment: Your macro does not work in Excel 2007, but the error is on `If Intersect ...` line.  Also, even with that corrected, it winds up in an infinite loop as each change you make in `copySub` will trigger the event macro again.  Are you sure you are explaining things as they are?  Is the Event Macro in the Sheet1 code module, or is it on some other worksheet?

Comment: It's is listed as a separate module... But Ambies answer solved my problem, so thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you've copied this code correctly? There's no way it would work in any version of Excel.

Your problems are these:

1. `Intersect` returns a `Range` object so your code would throw a 91 error.
2. There's most likely a case error in your line `Sheets("sheet1").Protect ...` as it's probably called "Sheet1". If so, this would throw a 91 error.
3. If you changed that worksheet name from "sheet1", it'd throw a 91 error.
4. Why are you only protecting the sheet at `Worksheet_Change`. This should really be done in `Workbook_Open`? And if you do that, how does the user change the cells without specific cells being free from protection?

It's unclear which worksheets you're referring to and where the `copySub` routine is held. I've updated your code as it is to remove the main errors and written in the capacity to nominate your worksheet - you'll have to adjust that as you wish. Good luck.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("C15:H15")) Is Nothing Then
        Call copySub(ws)
    End If
End Sub

Sub copySub(ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Protect , UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For i = 3 To 8
        ws.Cells(6, i).Value = ws.Cells(6, i).Value + ws.Cells(15, i).Value
        ws.Cells(15, i).Value = 0
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Short answer: it works now, thanks! Long answer: yes, I've copied it correctly, it's seems to be strange that it worked though... I've also changed the name of the worksheet because it's actually called 'Ratingen'... I have still one more question: do I have to pass in the worksheet as a parameter? Because I attached a button to the sub as well and this is not working anymore now. But I can live with that...

Comment: Ok, I tested it and I don't have to pass in the worksheet. Everything's working again now. Thanks again :)